# Why does bit-wise shift left return different results in Python and Java?

Tags: java, python, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I'm trying to port some functionality from a Java app to Python.

In Java,

```
System.out.println(155 << 24);
```

Returns: -1694498816

In Python:

```
print(155 << 24)
```

Returns 2600468480

Many other bitwise operations have worked in the same way in both languages. Why is there a different result in these two operations?

---

EDIT: I'm trying to create a function in python to replicate how the left shift operator works in Java. Something along the lines of:

```
def lshift(val, n):
    return (int(val) << n) - 0x100000000
```

However this doesn't seem right as (I think) it turns all numbers negatives?

---

EDIT2: Several hours later, I've decided it is probably not the best idea to use Python for this job and will take part of the Java application and use it as a micro service for the existing Python app.

Comment: Remember that Python's integers are not of a fixed bit width, they are arbitrary precision.

Comment: in this Python expression `155` means `155` in `binary` ,is this same as `Java`?

Comment: @Arman What do you mean by "`155` in binary"?

Comment: @SamTebbs33 , I mean `2` in binary is `10` and `155` in binary is `0b10011011`

Comment: FWIW, `(155<<24) - (1<<32) = -1694498816`

Comment: @Arman You don't think that Python and Java have their own concept of what's binary data, do you?

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you for the example, I've updated my question. Do you have any insight on if it possible to get the result Java gives, in Python when the result could be positive or negative?

Comment: @Arman Indeed, 2 binary is 10 and 155 in binary is 10011011. But what does that have to do with either Python or Java?

Comment: "Why is there a different result in these two operations?" Because Python does math correctly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are 3 different ways to convert a Python integer to its equivalent Java signed `int`. Note that these functions will *not* work correctly if the argument is wider than 32 bits, so you may wish to use bit masking on the argument before calling them.

The first way is to use the `struct` module to interpret the number as a 32 bit unsigned integer, pack it into bytes (using the local endian convention), and then unpack those bytes, interpreting them as a 32 bit signed integer. The other two methods use simple arithmetic with no function calls, so they are faster, but I guess they are a little harder to read.

This code was written on a 32 bit machine running Python 2.6.6, but it should run correctly on any architecture and version of Python (unless it's *extremely* ancient :) ).

```
from __future__ import print_function
from struct import pack, unpack

def ulong_to_long_pack(u):
    ''' using pack & unpack '''
    ubytes = pack('L', u)
    return unpack('l', ubytes)[0]

def ulong_to_long_sub(u):
    ''' using subtraction '''
    return u - (1<<32) if u >= (1<<31) else u

def ulong_to_long2_xor(u):
    ''' using exclusive OR '''
    return u ^ ~((1<<32)-1) if u & (1<<31) else u

funcs = (ulong_to_long_pack, ulong_to_long_sub, ulong_to_long2_xor)

# test
for ulong_to_long in funcs:
    print(ulong_to_long.__doc__)

    u = 2600468480
    print(u, ulong_to_long(u))

    big = 1<<31
    for u in range(big - 3, big + 3):
        print(u, ulong_to_long(u))

    print()
```

#### output

```
 using pack & unpack 
2600468480 -1694498816
2147483645 2147483645
2147483646 2147483646
2147483647 2147483647
2147483648 -2147483648
2147483649 -2147483647
2147483650 -2147483646

 using subtraction 
2600468480 -1694498816
2147483645 2147483645
2147483646 2147483646
2147483647 2147483647
2147483648 -2147483648
2147483649 -2147483647
2147483650 -2147483646

 using exclusive OR 
2600468480 -1694498816
2147483645 2147483645
2147483646 2147483646
2147483647 2147483647
2147483648 -2147483648
2147483649 -2147483647
2147483650 -2147483646
```

Comment: Java longs are 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks, @user2357112. I don't know Java (but I do know C); I've adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 21):

Java has 32-bit fixed width integers, so `155 << 24` shifts the uppermost set bit of `155` (which is bit 7, counting bits from zero, because 155 is greater than 2<sup>7</sup> but less than 2<sup>8</sup>) into the sign bit (bit 31) and you end up with a negative number.

Python has arbitrary-precision integers, so `155 << 24` is numerically equal to the positive number 155 × 2<sup>24</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use long in java to get the same result

```
System.out.println(155L << 24);
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(155 << 24);
```

Long are 4 byte length so the precision is the same for this context to python integers.